# How to prevent append from key in button to not add extra values when a new div is created

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel-blade

I've created a form which will add products to be key in details of the said products, each products will sometime have serialnumbers, users will need to click enabled serial numbers to start key in serial numbers.

So i have issue here whereby, when i add a new product, and key in serial number on product #1, it will have additional value added to it.

in a more detailed and simpler explanation;

Add Product  -> product #2 created.

enabled product #1 table to key in
value inputted to textarea became

```
SGH983819;
;
```

How do i go about to not let any previous product's key in not add on those `;\n` in any previous appended section?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  function enableSerial() {
    $('.enable-serial').on('change', function() {
      var item = $(this).data('item');
      $('.enable-' + item).prop('disabled', !this.checked);
    });
  }

  $('#add_product').on('click', function() {
    var itemNo = $('.product-item').length + 1;
    var appendData =  '<div class="product-item" data-item="' + itemNo +'">' +
    '<span>#' + itemNo +'</span>' +
    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger float-right remove_product"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>' +
    '<div class="form-group row">' +
      '<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Category</label>' +
      '<div class="col-sm-2">' +
        '<input class="form-control" name="products[' + (itemNo - 1) + ']category" type="text" placeholder="eg. 333" maxlength="3"required>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Code</label>' +
      '<div class="col-sm-2">' +
        '<input class="form-control" name="products[' + (itemNo - 1) + ']code" type="text" placeholder="eg. 22" maxlength="2" required>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Partnumber</label>' +
      '<div class="col-sm-2">' +
        '<input class="form-control" name="products[' + (itemNo - 1) + ']partnumber" type="text" placeholder="eg. NGH92838" required>' +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="form-group row">' +
      '<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Brand</label>' +
      '<div class="col-sm-2">' +
        '<input class="form-control" name="products[' + (itemNo - 1) + ']brand" type="text" placeholder="eg. Rototype" required>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Quantities</label>' +
      '<div class="col-sm-2">' +
        '<input class="form-control" name="products[' + (itemNo - 1) + ']qty" type="number" placeholder="eg. 1" required>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Location</label>' +
      '<div class="col-sm-2">' +
        '<input class="form-control location-ctrl-' + itemNo +' location-ctrl" data-item="' + itemNo +'" type="text" name="products[' + (itemNo - 1) + ']loc_name" list="locations" value="">' +
        '<input type="hidden" class="location-id-' + itemNo +'" name="products[' + (itemNo - 1) + ']location_id" value="">' +
        '<input type="hidden" class="loc-desc-' + itemNo +'" name="products[' + (itemNo - 1) + ']loc_desc" value="">' +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="form-group row">' +
      '<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Description</label>' +
      '<div class="col-sm-8">' +
        '<input class="form-control" name="products[0]description" type="text" placeholder="eg. Spare part for CSD2002">' +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="form-group row">' +
      '<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Serial Number(s)</label>' +
      '<div class="col-sm-5">' +
        '<input class="form-control enable-' + itemNo +' serial-' + itemNo +'" maxlength="25" placeholder="Key in Serial Number and hit button Key In" disabled>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<div class="col-sm-5">' +
        '<button class="btn btn-dark enable-' + itemNo +' keyin-ctrl-' + itemNo +' keyin-ctrl" data-item="' + itemNo +'" type="button" disabled>Key In</button>' +
        '<button class="btn btn-dark ml-1 enable-' + itemNo +' undo-ctrl-' + itemNo +' undo-ctrl" data-item="' + itemNo +'" type="button" disabled>Del</button>' +
        '<input class="form-check-input ml-4 mt-2 pointer enable-serial-' + itemNo +' enable-serial" data-item="'+ itemNo +'" id="checkbox-' + itemNo +'" type="checkbox">' +
        '<label class="form-check-label ml-5 pointer" for="checkbox-' + itemNo +'">tick to enable serialnumber</label>' +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="form-group row">' +
      '<label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>' +
      '<div class="col-sm-5">' +
        '<textarea class="form-control display-' + itemNo +'" name="products[' + (itemNo - 1) + ']serialnumbers" rows="5" style="resize: none;" placeholder="eg. SGH8484848" readonly></textarea>' +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<hr>' +
    '</div>';
    $('#append').append(appendData);
    enableSerial();
    ctrlSerial();
  });

  function ctrlSerial() {
    $('.keyin-ctrl').on('click', function() {
      var item = $(this).data('item');
      var result = $('.serial-' + item).val() + '; \n';
      $('.display-' + item).append(result);
      $('.serial-' + item).val('').focus();
    });

    $('.undo-ctrl').on('click', function() {
     var item = $(this).data('item');
     $('.display-' + item).html('');
    });
  }

  $('#append').on('click','.remove_product', function(){
    var itemNo = $('.product-item').length + 1;
    $(this).parent('div').remove();
    itemNo--;
  });

enableSerial();
ctrlSerial();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main class="shadow border">
    <h4>Product Details</h4>
    <hr>
    <h5>GRN Details</h5>
    <form method="post" action="">
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label font-weight-bold">GRN</label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" value="020719" name="nnmmyy" readonly>
          <input type="hidden" name="supp_name" value="ABCD Co. Ltd.">
          <input type="hidden" name="supp_do" value="DO97/39901/01">
          <input type="hidden" name="do_date" value="17/07/2019">
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Multiple Product addition -->
      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Product Setting</label><br/>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
          <button type="button" id="add_product" class="btn btn-dark">Add Product&nbsp;<i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <!-- Frist Group -->
      <div class="product" id="append">
        <!-- Product Details -->
        <div class="product-item" data-item="1">
          <span>#1</span>
          <div class="form-group row">
           <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Category</label>
           <div class="col-sm-2">
             <input class="form-control" name="products[0]category" type="text" placeholder="eg. 333" maxlength="3"required>
           </div>
           <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Code</label>
           <div class="col-sm-2">
             <input class="form-control" name="products[0]code" type="text" placeholder="eg. 22" maxlength="2" required>
           </div>
           <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Partnumber</label>
           <div class="col-sm-2">
            <input class="form-control" name="products[0]partnumber" type="text" placeholder="eg. NGH92838" required>
           </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Brand</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <input class="form-control" name="products[0]brand" type="text" placeholder="eg. Rototype" required>
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Quantities</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <input class="form-control" name="products[0]qty" type="number" placeholder="eg. 1" required>
            </div>
            <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Location</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <input class="form-control location-ctrl-1 location-ctrl" data-item="1" type="text" name="products[0]loc_name" list="locations" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="location_id-1" name="products[0]location_id" value="">
              <input type="hidden" class="loc_desc-1" name="products[0]loc_desc" value="">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Description</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input class="form-control" name="products[0]description" type="text" placeholder="eg. Spare part for CSD2002">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label font-weight-bold">Serial Number(s)</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <input class="form-control enable-1 serial-1" maxlength="25" placeholder="Key in Serial Number and hit button Key In" disabled>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <button class="btn btn-dark enable-1 keyin-ctrl-1 keyin-ctrl" data-item="1" type="button" disabled>Key In</button>
              <button class="btn btn-dark enable-1 undo-ctrl-1 undo-ctrl" data-item="1" type="button" disabled>Del</button>
              <input class="form-check-input ml-4 mt-2 pointer enable-serial-1 enable-serial" data-item="1" id="checkbox-1" type="checkbox">
              <label class="form-check-label ml-5 pointer" for="checkbox-1">tick to enable serialnumber</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label"></label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
              <textarea class="form-control display-1" name="products[0]serialnumbers" rows="5" style="resize: none;" placeholder="eg. SGH8484848" readonly></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
        </div>
      <!-- append start -->
      </div>
      
      <datalist id="locations">
          <option value="A0001" data-locationid="1" data-locdesc="Cabinet A"></option>
      </datalist>
    </form>
</main>
```

I in hope that there some suggestion or way to do it whereby wont have additional value added when keying previous product serial numbers

Answer (score 0):

found my own fix...

added `result.val('');` will reset any key in

```
function ctrlSerial() {
    $('.keyin-ctrl').on('click', function() {
      var item = $(this).data('item');
      var result = $('.serial-' + item).val() + '; \n';
      $('.display-' + item).append(result);
      $('.serial-' + item).val('').focus();
      result.val(''); // added this to also wipe clean properly
    });

    $('.undo-ctrl').on('click', function() {
        var item = $(this).data('item');
        $('.display-' + item).html('');
    });
  }
```